# Ethereum Smartcontracts with YottaChain

Tags: blockchain, storage, database

I am very much curious about this new storage system YottaChain.

Can someone point me good articles/videos/sources as a reference to go through and understand its implementation with ethereum smart-contracts?

Answer (score 1):

you can download the user guide from the [yottachain site](http://static.yottachain.net/download/YTA%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%A3%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3%20.pdf), and in general, there is a download [page](https://www.yottachain.io/developer/) where you can try to find some information.

There is the YottaChain  [Whitepaper](https://www.allcryptowhitepapers.com/yottachain-whitepaper/)